# Android Marshmallow crashes from device for camera

Tags: android, android-camera, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-camera-intent

In my Activity:

I called the camera action like this:

```
 private void selectImage() {
    final CharSequence[] items = {"Camera", "Choose from Library",
            "Cancel"};
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AccountsListActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
    builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            boolean result = Utility.checkPermission(AccountsListActivity.this);
            if (items[item].equals("Camera")) {
                userChoosenTask = "Camera";
                if (result)
                    cameraIntent();
            } else if (items[item].equals("Choose from Library")) {
                userChoosenTask = "Choose from Library";
                if (result)
                    galleryIntent();
            } else if (items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}
```

My cameraIntent() and galleryIntent are as follows:

```
private void galleryIntent() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);//
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"), SELECT_FILE);
}

private void cameraIntent() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Start the image capture intent to take photo
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }

}
```

I gave Marshmallow permissions like

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case Utility.MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (userChoosenTask.equals("Camera")) {
                    cameraIntent();
                } else if (userChoosenTask.equals("Choose from Library")) {
                    galleryIntent();
                }
            } else {
                //code for deny
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

My ActivityResult method

```
 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE)
                onSelectFromGalleryResult(data);
            else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA)
                onCaptureImageResult(data);
        }

}
```

Utility.class

```
 public class Utility {
public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 123;



@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
public static boolean checkPermission(final Context context)
{
    int currentAPIVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if(currentAPIVersion>=android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity) context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                alertBuilder.setCancelable(true);
                alertBuilder.setTitle("Permission necessary");
                alertBuilder.setMessage("External storage permission is necessary");
                alertBuilder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    //@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alert = alertBuilder.create();
                alert.show();

            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I am getting the Dialog box for selecting my option either for camera or gallery.
When I select the camera option the application is crashing. So I tried to run in debug mode and found that ActivityResult method is not executing.
I assume that I have declared all permissions for camera for Marshmallow.

Comment: you are missing runtime permissions show your code we will made some change then it works.

Comment: Check camera permission in App setting. Is it on? if not there may be something wrong with your mashmallow permission model implementation.

Comment: Its because run time permission i think.https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: @Praveen Kumar check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37946817/3117966) out for permissions

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-)
Please look at [ask]. This will help to get useful answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution for the webview.

for webview

```
  webView.setWebChromeClient(new PQChromeClient());
```

in PQChromeClient() method

```
  private class PQChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
  public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView view,ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePath,WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams){
        if (mFilePathCallback != null) {
            mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(null);
        }

        mFilePathCallback = filePath;
        if(getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                checkPermission();
            }
        }
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile1 = null;
            try {
                photoFile1 = createImageFile();
                takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCameraPhotoPath);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File
                Log.e(TAG, "Unable to create Image File", ex);
            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile1 != null) {
                mCameraPhotoPath = "file:" + photoFile1.getAbsolutePath();
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                        Uri.fromFile(photoFile1));
            } else {
                takePictureIntent = null;
            }
        }

        Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        contentSelectionIntent.setType("*/*");

        Intent[] intentArray;
        if (takePictureIntent != null) {
            intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
        } else {
            intentArray = new Intent[0];
        }

        Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser");
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE);
        return true;
    }
    private File createImageFile() throws IOException{
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File imageFile = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );
        return imageFile;
    }

    // openFileChooser for Android 3.0+
    public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType) {
        mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
        // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard
        File imageStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "AndroidExampleFolder");
        if (!imageStorageDir.exists()) {
            // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard
            imageStorageDir.mkdirs();
        }

        if(getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                checkPermission();
            }
        }

        // Create camera captured image file path and name
        File file = new File(imageStorageDir + File.separator + "IMG_"
                + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())
                + ".jpg");
        mCapturedImageURI = Uri.fromFile(file);

        // Camera capture image intent
        final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        i.setType("*/*");
        // Create file chooser intent
        Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(i, "Image Chooser");
        // Set camera intent to file chooser
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS
                , new Parcelable[]{captureIntent});
        // On select image call onActivityResult method of activity
        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);

    }

    // openFileChooser for Android < 3.0
    public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {
        openFileChooser(uploadMsg, "");
    }

    //openFileChooser for other Android versions
    public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg,
                                String acceptType,
                                String capture) {

        openFileChooser(uploadMsg, acceptType);
    }
}
```

and for permissions,

```
   private void checkPermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {//Can add more as per requirement
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                123);

    }
}
```

finally on ActivityResult

```
      @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        if (requestCode != INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE || mFilePathCallback == null) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            return;
        }
        Uri[] results = null;

        // Check that the response is a good one
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (data == null) {
                // If there is not data, then we may have taken a photo
                if (mCameraPhotoPath != null) {
                    results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCameraPhotoPath)};
                }
            } else {
                String dataString = data.getDataString();
                if (dataString != null) {
                    results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                }
            }
        }
        mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(results);
        mFilePathCallback = null;
    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        if (requestCode != FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE || mUploadMessage == null) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            return;
        }
        if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {
            if (null == this.mUploadMessage) {
                return;
            }
            Uri result = null;
            try {
                if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                    result = null;
                } else {
                    // retrieve from the private variable if the intent is null
                    result = data == null ? mCapturedImageURI : data.getData();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "activity :" + e,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
            mUploadMessage = null;
        }
    }

    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE_SELECT_IMAGE:
            if (mFilePathCallback == null || resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK || data == null) {
                //Reset during photo was not selected or canceled selection.
                resetToDefault();

                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                return;
            }
            String picturePath = data.getDataString();

            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(picturePath) /*&& new File(picturePath).exists()*/) {
                Log.d("picturePath", picturePath);
                setSelectedPhotoForFacebook(picturePath);

                //Reset during photo was not selected or canceled selection.
                resetToDefault();
            }
            break;

        default:
            Log.d("ERROR: ", "request code not matched");
            break;
    }
}
```

where

```
private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mFilePathCallback;
private String mCameraPhotoPath;
private static final int INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
private static final int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 2;
private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
private Uri mCapturedImageURI = null;
```

and in your Manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.front"
    android:required="true" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer on

### How to grant permission for an Android Web View?

1. Set a web chrome client. Your custom chrome client class extends **WebChromeClient**.

```java
webView.setWebChromeClient(new CustomChromeClient());
```

2. In your web chrome client override **onPermissionRequest**:

```java
@Override
public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {
    request.grant(request.getResources());
}
```

3. Optionally override **onPermissionRequestCanceled**:

```java
@Override
public void onPermissionRequestCanceled(PermissionRequest request) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onPermissionRequestCanceled");
}
```

Done.