# Capture Image From Camera and Select Image From Gallery of Android Phone Using Android Studio

Tags: android, camera, android-gallery, android-camera-intent

```js
package com.sourcey.materiallogindemo;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class Profile extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView viewImage;
    Button b;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
        b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSelectPhoto);
        viewImage=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.viewImage);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                selectImage();
            }
        });
    }



    private void selectImage() {

        final CharSequence[] options = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Gallery","Cancel" };

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Profile.this);
        builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
        builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                //boolean result=Utility.checkPermission(Profile.this);
                if (options[item].equals("Take Photo"))
                {


                  //  startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    File f = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");
                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
                    startActivityForResult(intent,1);
                }
                else if (options[item].equals("Choose from Gallery"))
                {
                    Intent intent = new   Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 2);

                }
                else if (options[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == 1) {
                File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
                for (File temp : f.listFiles()) {
                    if (temp.getName().equals("temp.jpg")) {
                        f = temp;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                try {
                    Bitmap bitmap;
                    BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();

                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(),
                            bitmapOptions);

                    viewImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                    String path = android.os.Environment
                            .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                            + File.separator
                            + "Phoenix" + File.separator + "default";
                    f.delete();
                    OutputStream outFile = null;
                    File file = new File(path, String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
                    try {
                        outFile = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, outFile);
                        outFile.flush();
                        outFile.close();
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else if (requestCode == 2) {

                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePath = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePath, null, null, null);
                c.moveToFirst();
                int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);
                String picturePath = c.getString(columnIndex);
                c.close();
                Bitmap thumbnail = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
                Log.w("path of image from gallery......******************.........", picturePath+"");
                viewImage.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am new to android.In my app ,i need to set picture from camera or gallery so i used this code(mentioned). gallery option is working fine but when i choose camera ,the app is unfortunately stopped,please help to fix it and i also save the picture in gallery which was taken in camera.

Comment: whats your targetSdk?

Comment: refer link https://github.com/coomar2841/image-chooser-library

Comment: Check this [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991319/capture-image-from-camera-and-display-in-activity). Hope this help you.

Comment: target sdk is API23 @Nisarg

Comment: @SriSoundhar you have to check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37946817/3117966) for api 23

Answer (score 0):

If you are having problem with the image from camera then you can use the following function.

```
public void fromCamera(){

String path= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/DCIM/Camera/";
File file = new File(path,"IMG_"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg");
file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
try {
    file.createNewFile();
}catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
mPicCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mPicCaptureUri);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);

}
```

And on your **OnActivityResult** you can get your image and do what you need to do:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
   if(requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA){

        if(mPicCaptureUri!=null){
            //do try to set image here ....
        }
    }
}
}
```

And yes do define at the top **mPicCaptureUri** as:

```
private Uri mPicCaptureUri = null;
```

It worked for me .. hope it helps..