# Ask Multiple Permissions Android

Tags: android, permissions

I'm modifying an existing Face Tracker app Android's Facial Recognition sample projects. I'm having an issue with requesting multiple permanent permissions. The method below is a modified version of the existing method that successfully creates a pop up window to ask for camera permissions. I'm trying to replicate this with the storage permissions but so far I've been unsuccessful and I'm not sure what needs to be changed here.

```
 private void requestAllPermissions() {
    Log.w(TAG, "Camera + Storage permissions are not granted. Requesting permissions");

    final String[] permissions = new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA};
    final String[] permissions2 = new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};


    if (!ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, RC_HANDLE_CAMERA_PERM);
        return;
    }

    //new
    if (!ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions2, RC_HANDLE_STORAGE_PERM);
        return;
    }


    final Activity thisActivity = this;

    View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity, permissions,
                    RC_HANDLE_CAMERA_PERM);
        }
    };

    View.OnClickListener listener2 = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity, permissions2,
                    RC_HANDLE_STORAGE_PERM);
        }
    };

    Snackbar.make(mGraphicOverlay, R.string.permission_camera_rationale,
            Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
            .setAction(R.string.ok, listener)
            .show();

    Snackbar.make(mGraphicOverlay, R.string.permission_storage_rationale,
            Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
            .setAction(R.string.ok, listener2)
            .show();
}
```

Comment: Why do you have *four* `requestPermissions()` calls? `requestPermissions()` takes an array of permission names, not just one. This should be consolidated into one `requestPermissions()` call.

Comment: The original code has two request permission calls for the camera alone, I was unsure why but replicated it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to ask multiple permissions at same time in Android Marshmelllow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38582470/how-to-ask-multiple-permissions-at-same-time-in-android-marshmelllow)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you should have only one String array if you want to ask all permissions in one dialog box, like this:

```
int ALL_PERMISSIONS = 101;

final String[] permissions = new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};

ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, ALL_PERMISSIONS);
```

Comment: Simple and perfect

Answer (score 3):

What you have to do is just put the permission sin a String array like

```
int PERMISSION_ALL = 1;
String[] PERMISSIONS = {
        android.Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS,
        android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
};
```

and to Check the permission use then

```
public static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
    if (context != null && permissions != null) {
        for (String permission : permissions) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Now the Last thing to do finally is use it in oncreate() or onStart()

```
if(!hasPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS)){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to request permissions multiple times. The requestpermission method accepts array of Permissions. To request for any permission you can use the below code and add the permissions you need. This is how you handle runtime permissions by requesting them before accessing any data related to permission

```
public  boolean isStoragePermissionGranted() {
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {

    if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
        return true;
    } else {

        Log.v(TAG,"Permission is revoked");
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 1);
        return false;
    }
}
else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
    Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
    return true;
}
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 0:
            boolean isPerpermissionForAllGranted = false;
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && permissions.length==grantResults.length) {
                for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++){
                    if (grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                        isPerpermissionForAllGranted=true;
                    }else{
                        isPerpermissionForAllGranted=false;
                    }
                }

                Log.e("value", "Permission Granted, Now you can use local drive .");
            } else {
                isPerpermissionForAllGranted=true;
                Log.e("value", "Permission Denied, You cannot use local drive .");
            }
            if(isPerpermissionForAllGranted){
                shoro();
            }
            break;
        }
    }
```

Once you do that, for devices with API >=23 You will get popup at runtime and then once the user accepts the permission or rejects it, your `onRequestPermissionsResult` method is called. so here you will have to handle your check whether user granted the app the permission. If yes you can continue with your logic

Answer (score 1):

I faced the issue today and answer from Aman Grover actually worked for me, you simple need to do following

```
final String[] permissions = new String[]{ 
    android.Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS, 
    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
};

ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, 123);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest solution:

> Add this code in your MainActivity's onCreate method

```js
//Requesting permissions
        int PERMISSION_ALL = 1;
        String[] PERMISSIONS = {
                android.Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS,
                android.Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
                android.Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE,
        };

        if (!hasPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);
        }
```

> Now, add this function in your main activity class

```js
public static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
    if (context != null && permissions != null) {
        for (String permission : permissions) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

You can add ass many permissions you need to ask at the application startup.