# How to turn off/on app level permission programmatically in android

Tags: android, settings, android-permissions, user-permissions, application-settings

How can I allow/deny any permissions like location/Notification Programmatically for an specific app in android.

Like on below popup I have to perform an action like:-

1) On Allow :- Location Permission should turn ON for this app.

2) On Don't Allow :- Location Permission should turn OFF for this app.

[image]

Comment: Check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45467618/ask-multiple-permissions-android/45467783#45467783

Comment: @kapsym: Your link is for requesting runtime permissions in your own app. The OP is attempting to control runtime permissions of other apps.

Comment: Outside of perhaps some device owner APIs, or perhaps on a rooted device, what you want is not possible, for blindingly obvious security reasons.